# Make Xmonad deal with shift levels in a more standard way

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmonad

**Summary:** I want Xmonad to register keypresses like `Mod-Shift-k`
as `Mod-K`.  In other words, I don’t want the shift key to be registered
similarly to how the `Mod` key is registered.  (I use `Super` as the
`Mod` key, while `Alt` is the default.)

---

What I am used to in most applications is that hotkeys are sensitive to
the shift level of the key that I am pressing.  For example, if I press
`Ctrl-k`, this is treated differently than `Ctrl-K`.  Further, the
application does not care why the `K` is capital (majuscule); it acts
the same whether it was produced due to `Shift` being held down, `Caps Lock` being triggered, or something else.

The way that Xmonad seems to work by default is that it registers shift
keys like the regular shift key and the level 3 (`AltGr` on European
keyboards) and level 5 as most applications treat keys like `Ctrl` and
`Alt`.  That is, it treats the keybinding “Super Shift and k” pressed
at the same time as `Super-Shift-k`, *not* as `Super-K`.  I want the
latter behavior; I want Xmonad to only care about the key that was
produced due to keys like `Shift` being depressed, *not* whether `Shift`
was depressed.

The motivation for this is that I have a keymapping with the numerals
located on one of the “shift levels” (i.e., not the first level) of
some keys that are not the regular “number keys”.  So in order to access
them, I need to press some modifier keys.  But this creates a problem
when I want to change the workspace, as Xmonad seems to register things
like `Super-Shift3-k` as “`k` with `Super` and `Shift3` depressed” instead
of `Super-3` (assuming that `Shift3-k` produces the symbol `3`).